# In C++ should derived class pointer point to base class pointer?

Tags: c++, stack

I've very rare error and to understand the reason I need to know some facts of C++. Let me explain the problem:

There is such structure:

```
struct Base;                 // not polimorfic
class Derived : public Base; // has pure virtual
class ImplDerived : public Derived    // implements pure virtuals

some_function(Base* base);
int main() {
    ImplDerived impd;
    some_function(&impd);
}
```

Now, what's happening is this:

- Running on **desktop linux** environment:

  No error.

  Inside `some_function`, **base** pointer points to the same address of **&impd**. In other words, in memory, ImplDerived object starts with `Base` object. i.e, when I'm debugging, I see this:

  ```
  ImplDerived  : 0xab00

    -> Derived : 0xab00

      -> Base  : 0xab00
  ```
- Running on **embedded linux** in embedded device (compiled with its compiler):

  Error.

  Inside `some_function`, **base** pointer points again to **&impd**.

  However, this time it is not the right place where **base** is. Because now
  **base** starts at **&impd** **+4** bytes.

  When I'm debugging I see this:

  ```
  ImplDerived  : 0xab00

    -> Derived : 0xab00

      -> Base  : 0xab04
  ```

**Questions:**

- AFAIK, the offset between base and derived pointer is permittible, **right**?
- If it is, then should not the implicit casting when passing the pointer to the `some_function` find where the `base` is?
- If it should, then would it be some error in compilation?

Thanks.

**Compilers:**

- Desktop: gcc 4.9.2-10 Debian 64 bits
- Embedded: gcc 4.8.0

**EDIT (RESULT):**

After all tests, we have decided that this is a compiler error. Casting just does not work correctly, i) for non-polymorphic base, ii) for multiple inheritance.

Comment: Even if an error might not be relevant, it's always good to show errors, because we don't *know* if it's relevant or not. Also, when there's a difference between compilers it's good to tell us *what* compilers (including versions of them) are used.

Comment: I'm puzzled about the case (on desktop linux) where the base and derived addresses are the same.  You have different addresses - why does this cause difficulty?

Comment: Actually because of this shift of memory in some_function, any error would arise. because "base" does not point to base anymore. In my case, it is segmentation fault.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I've added compilers

Comment: What is "its compiler"? Can you show a conplete program?

Comment: I think you should specify which kind of embedded linux you are working on. Maybe someone with access the same device can help. Your snippet is correct c++ and should just run fine. Possibly the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: "Actually because of this shift of memory in some_function, any error would arise. because "base" does not point to base anymore. "  That doesn't make sense.  There *is* no "base" object at 0xab00.  The base object is at 0xab04.  We need a [mcve]

Comment: @Martin Bonner what makes sense is, in some_function this shift is not seen. This is the problem. There is no base object at 0xab00 but the pointer points exactly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AFAIK, the offset between base and derived pointer is permittible, right?

It is permitted, yes. In fact, it's mandatory if the derived class has multiple (non-empty) base classes, since all of the base class sub objects cannot share the same address. But even a sole base class sub object might not share the derived object's address, as you have observed.

> If it is, then should not the implicit casting when passing the pointer to the some_function find where the base is?

Yes. When the derived pointer is implicitly converted to the base pointer, it should be pointing to the base sub object.

> If it should, then would it be some error in compilation?

Maybe, the example code should be just fine, but it's incomplete.

Answer (score 3):

No, pointers to base and derived classes do not have to match. Especially this happens when multiple inheritance is used. In your case the reason seems different. Because the base class is not polymorphic, it does not have a virtual table pointer as its hidden member. However, the polymorphic derived classes start to have virtual table pointer. I guess you are compiling in 32-bit, so that's where 4 bytes offset arises: that pointer is 32-bit.

`dynamic_cast` should solve your problem.

Comment: static_cast is 100% OK for this case as it is an upcast, and your compiler knows the actual type of your ImplDerived anyway. This is a perfect example of when you do not need a dynamic_cast.

Comment: @Serge Rogatch you pointed out so good: Desktop is 64-bit where embedded is 32 bit. dynamic_cast simply did not compile it, giving the error: Base is not polimorfic.

Comment: @MertMertce, have you tried `some_function(static_cast<Base*>(&impd));` in your `main` function? I see 1 more potential problem in your code: could you try changing the declaration for `Base` from `struct` to `class`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried explicit casting and the same, not tried class insteaf of struct though.